# SQL insert row if field has changed (high performance)

Tags: sql, postgresql

My Table has these fields:

```
SENSOR_ID INTEGER, 
SENSOR_READING REAL, 
TIME_OF_READING TIMESTAMP, 
HASCHANGED BOOLEAN
```

Each sensor fires >10'000 readings/day. I want to log only those datapoints where SENSOR_READING is different from the last logged value.

Alternatively, I may log everything but set HASCHANGED to true whenever SENSOR_READING is different from the last logged value.

What is the most performant syntax for accomplishing that (with PostgreSQL, without php logics)?

Comment: you should not use `REAL` if you need accurant readings. You should use `NUMERIC` instead.

Comment: Why not store the last reading in memory in your app that is monitoring the sensor and only log to the database if it changes.

Comment: With the `UNIQUE` constraint you can't log all readings. Unless you want to only have the last reading. Is it the case?

Comment: Thank you all. I started receiving help from you exactly 28 seconds after posting. I am impressed and truly grateful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this

```
insert into readings (sensor_id, sensor_reading, time_of_reading)
select 42, 1234.5678, current_timestamp
from readings
where not exists (select * 
                  from readings 
                  where sensor_reading = 1234.5678
                    and time_of_reading = (select max(time_of_reading)
                                           from readings
                                           where sensor_id = 42);
```

This will require the `sensor_reading` column to be indexed but I still doubt that it will actually be faster.

You don't need to store the `haschanged` attribute because you can calculate that while retrieving the data:

```
select sensor_id,
       sensor_reading,
       time_of_reading,
       lag(sensor_reading) over (partition by sensor_id order by time_of_reading) = sensor_reading as has_changed
from readings;
```

This assumes that `sensor_id` isn't actually unique, otherwise you couldn't store more than one reading for a sensor

It further assumes that you change that `REAL` column to a `NUMERIC` column, because `REAL` values using `=` isn't accurate (actually the storing isn't accurate to begin with)

Comment: what if the sensor reading matches an older (not the last) reading? FWIW, I think his schema design is badly broken.

Comment: @Bohemian: good point. I think Eugen's idea is the best so far.

Comment: @a_horse, I would tend to favor your proposal because it does not require an additional table. I will try it and also Eugen's, and report back. Many thanks to all of you!

Answer (score 2):

You should have a table with the sensors and their current readings, and `UPDATE` it on the sensor event. Then use a trigger to write to the log table if the new reading differs.

Comment: Great suggestion, many thanks. I cannot vote you up because I am a novice and I am not (yet) entitled to!

Comment: Also add an "on insert" trigger on the sensor event. That could be used to feed new sensor_ids to the "receptor" table, once they occur for the first time. (in fact, this is an "upsert" to the "receptor" table )

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that you have to add a column where place the last value, then at every "read" you can make a comparison between those two columns.

This is a "pure sql" approach but there are solution much better, like callback (you told about php so i suggest symfony and doctrine that can do that for you and this is a valid approach if you have to do some step if the values are changed or something like this...)